# Excel formula for calculating average of duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate, average

I have certain repeated values in the first column. I want to average out those values based on the number of times they are repeating themselves. I want the results in the adjacent columns.

Something like below:

- There are 10 12100 values, so average is 1210
- There are 5 4550 values, so average is 910

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your use of average is not entirety correct, but I think I get what your after.

Assuming you data is in column A, use this in B1 and drag down:

```
=A1/COUNTIFS(A:A,A1)
```

FYI the average of 10 values all equalling 12100 is actually 12100.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this! By average I meant I needed to divide it in equal parts in the number of times it is repeating itself. :)

Comment: @Sheenam if this has helped solve you issue, please mark as correct by clicking the little tick mark next to this answer, and welcome to SuperUser !

Comment: This did not work as exactly as I hoped it would. I am Attaching another screen grab to explain the problem

It is taking into consideration all the (same) numbers in the list and then giving me an average. What I want instead is the average of the numbers repeating consecutively.

Implying, if 3615 repeats 4 times in column A1 to A4 I should get 903.75 in B1 to B4. 

Also, If it is repeating again in A24 to A28, I should be able to get 903.75 in B24 to B28

Comment: @Sheenam add the images to your question, I will take a look for you

Comment: I have added the picture to the edit and as a new comment. You will be able to see that soon.

Answer (score 0):

@PeterH if you see in the attached picture 3615 is repeated 4 times but it gives 451, instead of giving me 903.75 four times.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkanM.jpg)